# PL/SQL Trigger throws a MUTATING TABLE error

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have this trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TR14_2 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CANTIDAD ON DISTRIBUCION 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  total_cars NUMBER;
  total_cars_potential NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(cantidad) into total_cars
    FROM DISTRIBUCION
    WHERE cifc = :NEW.cifc;
  total_cars_potential := total_cars + :NEW.cantidad;

  IF INSERTING THEN
    IF(total_cars_potential > 40) THEN
      raise_application_error(-20005, 'Dealer [' || :NEW.cifc || '] already has 40 cars stocked');
    END IF;
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING THEN
    IF(total_cars_potential - :OLD.cantidad > 40) THEN
      raise_application_error(-20006, 'That update of CANTIDAD makes the dealer exceeds the limit of 40 cars stocked');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

It gets a mutating table error, and I have checked that is because of the UPDATING block of code, the INSERTING goes ok; but why? And how can I fix it?

Just to clarify, I want that each dealer can have at maximum 40 cars stocked. So, if I add a row to DISTRIBUCION ("distribution") with cantidad ("quantity") that will make the dealer exceed its maximum stock, I will raise an error.
But, if I update a quantity of cars of a type, stocked already in the database, and I exceed 40 cars, I want also a exception to be thrown.

Thing is, I am not seeing the mutatig table error on the UPDATING block.

Comment: Check this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: The reason you get a mutating table syndrome is that you're reading from the table that is updated in the trigger (selecting the total cars).

2nd: Solution: I'd probably create 2 triggers: A for-each-row trigger as you did that collects the updated rows in a package variable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PCK_TR14_2 IS
  TYPE changed_row IS RECORD (
        cantidad                DISTRIBUCION.cantidad%TYPE,
  );
  TYPE changed_row_table IS TABLE OF changed_rows INDEX BY binary_integer;
  changed_rows changed_row_table;
  cnt_changed_rows   BINARY_INTEGER   DEFAULT   1;
END PCK_TR14_2;
/
```

The for-each-row trigger would look something like this (now an after insert!)

```
create or replace TRIGGER TR14_2 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CANTIDAD ON DISTRIBUCION 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PCK_TR14_2.changed_rows(PCK_TR14_2.cnt_changed_rows).cantidad := :old.cantidad;
  PCK_TR14_2.cnt_changed_rows := PCK_TR14_2.cnt_changed_rows + 1;
END;
/
```

Then in a after statement trigger implement your logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR14_2_S
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CANTIDAD ON DISTRIBUCION 
BEGIN
  FOR i IN PCK_TR14_2.changed_rows.FIRST..PCK_TR14_2.changed_rows.LAST LOOP
    -- YOUR LOGIC HERE
    null;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Access the candidat in the "virtuell" table as needed ( PCK_TR14_2.changed_rows(i). CANTIDAD)

Comment: Thanks it is a bit complicated for what we do in class but it seems it could go ok, I will try it out and see one of these days thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can not change a table that it has read from. This is the mutating table error issue.

You can see the solutions provided in the below link
[Mutating table error](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions)

[avoiding_mutating_table_error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm)

Comment: But, as far as I'm concerned, I'm not changing anything in the table where the trigger points. I just read the :OLD and :NEW values and assign them to variables.